# Programmatically added macro to excel doesn´t appear after workbook is saved

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

i wanted to add an existing macro (auto_open.bas) to many excel sheets. Therefore i wrote an vbscript to add this macro. In debugging mode i can see that the macro is being appended to the VBComponents "list". It seems that everything worked nice and it saves the workbook. But if i open the workbook(s) i can´t see the macro in the executable list.
Could you please give me an advise?

```
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
        objExcel.Visible = False
        objExcel.WindowState = -4137
        Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(path)
        objWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(pathToMacro & "auto_open.bas")
        objWorkbook.Save
        objWorkbook.Close
        objExcel.quit
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with this SaveAs method

"objWorkbook.SaveAs Datei, 52"

52 = means that the workbook will be saved as a macro enabled workbook